# Family Sharing Purchases

Tags: apple-id, family-sharing

I am in the process of moving from an old Apple ID to a new one.

I will refer to the old ID as `ABC` and the new one as `XYZ`.

I currently have a family sharing setup on `ABC` with a couple of other family members. I plan to switch over to using `XYZ` as my main ID.

I plan to setup a new family using `XYZ` and add my family members to that family.

I have some purchases on `ABC` that I would like to retain.

If I add `XYZ` to this family, install those purchases from `ABC` on `XYZ`, and then set up a new family with `XYZ` as organizer, will `XYZ` still have access to those purchases?

Comment: I'm not putting this as an answer because I don't have sufficient detail.  But I once read instructions somewhere on how to transfer purchases from one Apple ID to another.  If you do that, of course the receiving ID will have access, but the source will not.

Answer (score 1):

My previous answer was not entirely accurate. I went through this exact scenarios a few days ago so here are my best tips to maximize an easy transition:

- Make a list of purchases you want to retain and check if they are compatible with family sharing (for IAPs)
- Create your new ID if needed, setup a family account (best done on a new user account on macOS + iCloud Beta)
- Add your family and your old account (you must have enough space for everyone for this to work or remove a family member from your life it's up to you :D)
- Log out of iCloud on your devices that use your old ID, log with the new one and everything should either sync to your new ID or just stay there as it should

Hope this helps future readers!